# Is the "except for/in spite of" meaning of "with" considered standard English?

Tags: meaning

Merriam-Webster claims that "with" can be used to say "except for" or "in spite of." They provide two examples:

> "a really tip-top man, *with all his wrongheadedness*" —H. J. Laski
>
> "finds that, *with one group of omissions and one important addition*,
> they reflect that curriculum" —Gilbert Highet

Having never encountered this particular usage, I can't help wondering how common it is. Is it colloquial English? Would the average native speaker understand it if someone were to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with) gives the sense

> **with** (preposition) (DESPITE)
>
> ​
>   *despite something*:
>
> With all her faults, she's still a really good friend.

with no caveats.

Macmillan (sense 9b), AHD (sense 11) and Collins (sense 5) concur, but apparently ODO and RHK Webster's miss this sense.

'For' is used in the same way:

*a really tip-top man, for all his wrongheadedness*.

I'd say that the variant using 'for' is usually more idiomatic (where available)  and less likely to confuse, and would be better with the first example here. And that with the second example, 'except for' is the corresponding choice.